# Passing a Bash shell variable into AppleScript file

Tags: bash, shell, applescript

I am currently learning how to use bash shell scripting with AppleScript. I have a problem.
The problem is how to pass a bash variable into an osascript
The example is as following:

```
read input
foo $input

foo(){
    osascript path/to/script.scpt $1
}
```

my question is how to convert input into something that would be accepted by the script.scpt since $1 would not be recognized by the script.scpt . Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually that should work since bash will automatically set the value of `$1` to be the argument you passed to `foo`. So in this scenario, it would be the input that you read.

I cleaned up you bash script a little..

```sh
#!/bin/bash

foo(){
  echo "Calling Apple script with argument $1"
  osascript script.scpt "$1"
}

read input
foo "$input"
```

And with this AppleScript,

```
on run argv
  return "hello, " & item 1 of argv & "."
end run
```

I get this output..

```
> ./test.sh
crazy world
Calling Apple script with argument world
hello, crazy world.
```

Comment: what if the value of $1 is a string with spaces? I used the run handler to split the string but it does not work.  For example, the value of $1 is "About This Mac,Apple" . I changed the delimiter from space to "," so that it should be parsed to "About This Mac" and "Apple", which are the two items of argv that I need. But it does not seem to work

Comment: Ah yes. That can be solved with a few quotes.. I will update the answer above.

Comment: This is a great read to avoid common gotcas in bash https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls

Comment: Thanks so much !